# Best feature selection method for wholeslide images

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have been working on extracting features from wholelside images in MATLAB. In that, i have so far succeeded in extracting 118 features from 92 training images. I want to select the feature that provides best two-class separability, the two classes being 'Infected' and 'Normal'. I evaluated the ks-density plot of each of the feature but couldn't get a numerical measure of the amount of overlap between the pdfs of a given feature from 'Normal' class and 'Infected' class.

Further, I tried ranking the features based on the method given in this paper: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0082710#pone.0082710-Newcombe1.

But this method seems to point the best feature as something which has considerable amount of overlap of pdfs between the two classes. When I test the accuracy of the method by measuring the Bhattacharya distance between the feature vector of the two classes, it shows some other set of features that are best.

I am not able to decide which method to use for feature selection. Can someone give me some guidance?

My goal is to correlate the amount of overlap between the pdfs of the feature vector of the two classes with the results of a proper feature selection algorithm. In other words, what the chosen algorithm points out as the best feature for classification should have the least pdf overlap.<\p>

If also someone can give me guidance on how I can estimate the amount of overlap between a given feature vector of class 'Normal' and the same feature vector of class 'Infected', that would be great.

Comment: I'd use the [AUC of the ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) as a generic measure of (non-) overlap.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for stats.SE. If you agree, flag your question and ask a moderator to move it there.